# HTTP POST data to php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, function, http, post

I have a webserver that is collecting incoming HTTP POST messages from a log collection server. I am attempting to collect the incoming post data with a php script and then download it into mysql. I have limited experience with both php and mysql.

Here is the script I have been working on, but I can't seem to get it working:

```
<?php
ob_start();
print_r($_REQUEST);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "XXXX", "XXXX");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `XXXX` VALUES ('$data')");
Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
?>
```

I'm not sure where I am failing here, and would appreciate any help! I did replace the password to my webserver and the database name with XXXX if you were wondering.

I was able to successfully log into mysql with this script, but it seems that my collection of POST data using PHP is not working quite right.

Thank You

Comment: Try printing out your SQL statement to see if it's even valid. My guess is $data is not in the right format for sticking in a value list in an SQL insert. Because using ob_start(); and ob_get_contents(); to convert post data to a list of values is just silly.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ob_start();
print_r($_REQUEST);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Why are you doing this? All you're going to get is a string of whatever is in the `$_POST` array, which is very likely not going to match up with the columns/values you need.

1. `XXXX` should be the database table name, not the database name
2. Your insert statement is a little funky. Read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html). At the very least, specify the column names:

   INSERT INTO `tablename` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ("value1", "value2")
3. Extract the values you expect from the `$_POST` like thus: `$_POST['keyname']`, where you'd replace *keyname* with your own.